# function move_uploaded_file() doesnt return a true result

Tags: php, upload

i try move_uploaded_file(),
i need the true or false result
but i doesnt return false ! it always return true!

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['form_pic']['tmp_name'][$i], $dest.$picture_name);
```

i want to know what are file field are filled

```
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<5 ; $i++ )
            {

             move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['form_pic']['tmp_name'][$i], $dest.$picture_name);
            {
```

Comment: The title and question contradict eachother.

Comment: What is your question? Title says that move_uploaded_file does'nt return true. Can you please post your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Without your html is hard to say but most definitely `$_FILES['form_pic']['tmp_name']` is not an array so you should try `$_FILES['form_pic'][$i]['tmp_name]`.

Comment: the important notice that is : i post my file with ajax (using iframe)